# FB Prophet Dataframe Issue

Tags: facebook-prophet

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Public\Meds.csv', header=None)
df.head()

0   1
0   ds  y
1   2023-01-01  102
2   2023-01-02  114
3   2023-01-03  123
4   2023-01-04  116

I get this output when running  m.fit(df).

I have two columns one with the date formatted as year month day and the second column with number values.

The first column has ds and the second has y so nothing complicated with the csv file. Any help why Prophet can't work with the csv would be appreciated.

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[141], line 1
----> 1 m.fit(df)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py:1117, in Prophet.fit(self, df, **kwargs)
1114     raise Exception('Prophet object can only be fit once. '
1115                     'Instantiate a new object.')
1116 if ('ds' not in df) or ('y' not in df):
-> 1117     raise ValueError(
1118         'Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and '
1119         'values respectively.'
1120     )
1121 history = df[df['y'].notnull()].copy()
1122 if history.shape[0] < 2:

ValueError: Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and values respectively.

made sure ds and y are lower case and are in the correct columns. I can send the example sheet if it would help.